# I want a macro to take the 1st 4 rows from all spreadsheets and put into a new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have less knowledge on excelsheets and macros. By looking at the articles i understood the usage of macros and creating them. I have a set of agencies and each agancy having a spreadsheet with some details. Everytime the 1st four rows are copied and pasted in new spreadsheet and put on sharepoint which is time consuming. If you can answer this question it helps the company save alot of time. I want a macro to automatically take the 1st 4 rows of all the spreadsheets and put into a new document and upload on sharepoint.

Comment: So record one and look at the code it generates. We're not really a site for "Here are my needs. Write the code for me. Be back later to pick it up." questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let call the 2 workbooks as "From" and "Destination" workbook

Open the "Destination workbook.
Then open the "From" workbook

Then press Alt+F11

Then Insert > Module

Then copy this and paste in the Module1

```
Sub copy()
Dim count As Integer
i = 0
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In Workbooks(1).Worksheets
i = i + 4
sheet.Rows("1:4").copy Workbooks(2).Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i - 3 & ":" &  i)
Next
End Sub
```

Then goto Developer Tab and click "Macros"

Click "copy" and click run

Comment: Thanks Abu Nayeem. But the code when run shows an error runtime error 9. Sorry but I am new to macros and excel but its a requirement for me.

Comment: In "Destination" workbook you need to rename a sheet as "Sheet1"